# High Sierra Mail Preferences Missing

Tags: macos, mail.app

When I go to "Preferences", a window named "Signatures" appears, which is empty. All my many previously saved Signatures are gone, and there is no way to access Mail Preferences.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you have a Time Machine (or other) backup that you can restore the files, which are located in

`~/Library/Mail/V5/MailData/Signatures`

and the files seem to be called by some sort of PID string ending with ".mailsignature"

Restore those files from backup to get your signatures back.